# Css: paragraph at bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

i have this html structure:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  
}
.grid-left {

  border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
   padding-top:4px;
  padding-bottom:4px;
 
}
.grid-right{

  border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-bottom:4px;
   padding-left: 15px;
}

.sub-grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
grid-template-rows: 26px auto auto;
border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
margin-bottom: 8px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-top: 3px;
}
.grid-text{
    padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 13px;
    color: #505050;


}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">     
    <div class="grid-left">
         <div class="sub-grid-container">
            <div class="negozio"> Amazon</div>
            <div class="img">Image</div>
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
   <div class="grid-right">   some text here .... <p> Date xx/xx/xx</p>         </div>
</div>
```

I want to have the paragraph p with the date at the bottom of the div, i tried using position absolute and relative but i have some problem like you see in the image [image] 
how can i fix this?

Comment: It's unclear if you want the <p> to be at the bottom (and of which div in the hierarchy) or you want div.grid-right to appear at the bottom.

Also, is it bottom right or left?

Comment: i'm sorry, i want the <p> at the bottom of grid-right (bottom left). The image i post shows only grid-right

Comment: I can't see how the code in  the question relates to the screen shot.

Comment: I agree with @MrLister, you should wither put a link to jsfiddle in this case or attach an image that relates to your code.

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm very bad to explain. The code is the current structure that i want to edit. The image refers to an edit that i don't write, i simply put position:absolute to grid-right, and (position:relative, bottom:0px) to the class of <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `position:relative` so that the div knows you are going to position another element inside that div.

Give your `.grid-container` a height (just for demo purposes)

```
.grid-cotainer { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  height: 200px }
```

Then tell the 'container' div `.grid-right` it needs relative positioning.

```
.grid-right {  
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative }
```

Then you can use what you used, `position:absolute` to keep it at the bottom.

```
.grid-right p:not(.not-at-bottom) {
  bottom: 0;
  position:absolute }
```

You could even make use of `not`. An identifier so that if you do not want to place a `p` tag at the bottom inside your `.grid-right` div, it knows not to.

https://jsfiddle.net/9rdbd4j6/

Comment: i tried to use your code, but i still have the problem of the image i post: if the text fill the div, the paragraph overlaps the text

Comment: Add some padding so that the div doesn't overlap the date: https://jsfiddle.net/9rdbd4j6/1/

Comment: yeah I didn't think about it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-left">
    <div class="sub-grid-container">
      <div class="negozio"> Amazon</div>
      <div class="img">Image</div>
      <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-right"> some text here ....
    <p> Date xx/xx/xx</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.grid-left {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.grid-right {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.grid-right p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: 26px auto auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.grid-text {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #505050;
}
```

Or run it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ur4jb9pc/
Basically:

- Set parent div with position: relative
- Set child p with position: absolute
- Set child p with bottom: 0